# Qt JsonObjects and initializer lists -- deeper than one level?

Tags: c++, qt

This is in the documentation:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsonobject.html#QJsonObject-1

Which shows that I can do:

```
QJsonObject o
{
    {"x", 1},
    {"y", 2}
}
```

...and that works, however

```
QJsonObject o
{
    {"x", { "value", 1 } },
    {"y", { "value", 2 } }
}
```

Does not compile.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to specify the type (QJsonObject or QJsonArray) in front of the initializer list {}, the compiler is unable to guess which one you want.

```
QJsonObject o
{
    {"x", QJsonObject { {"key", "value"} }}
};
```

Comment: Ah!  I had tried that, but not with double braces... Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. The need for the double braces should be clear when you try doing the same with a temporary variable for the inner QJsonObject.

Answer (score -1):

You could also try this approach, using C++11 [raw string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
const QByteArray object = R"(
    {
        "x": { "value": "1" },
        "y": { "value": "2" }
    }
)";

QJsonObject jsonObject = QJsonDocument::fromJson(object).object();
qDebug() << jsonObject;
```