# Qt QJsonObjects - list deeper than one level?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Contrary to this link, how to list the value of y and value:

[Qt JsonObjects and initializer lists -- deeper than one level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647381/qt-jsonobjects-and-initializer-lists-deeper-than-one-level)

```
QJsonObject o
{
    {"x", QJsonObject { {"value", 1} }},
    {"y", QJsonObject { {"value", 2} }}
};
```

The way below doesn't work:

```
int number = obj.value("y", "value");
```

I hope to receive the amount below:

number = 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @JimmyG, this way it worked, I don't know if it's a correct way, I got it by trial and error.

```
qDebug() << o.value("y").toObject().value("value").toInt();
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like:

```
int number = object.value("y").toJsonObject().value("value").toInt();
```

I might not have that exactly right, but you should get the idea...